# jquery to select second row column using first row column <td> in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I want to select second row second column using first row second column `<td>` tag in html table.

Example:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td id="amount-paid">$1.00 USD</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Row 2</td>
  <td>$2.69 USD</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Now I need to change the Row 2 second column value to "**Paid**" message.
This I need to do by using the first row second column id "**amount-paid**".

I tried the below code but it not worked:

```
$('#amount-paid td:eq(2)').text('Paid');
```

[image: It looks like this]

Comment: `eq()` is zero based. Try `eq(1)`.

Comment: I need to access based on td ID only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
$('#amount-paid td:eq(1)').text('Paid');
```

How about these?

```
$('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').text("Paid")
```

or

```
$('#amount-paid').closest('tr').next().find('td:eq(1)').text('Paid');
```

Comment: I made a small change in code it is work for this code.can u post again the answer

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
$('table tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(1).text('Paid');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td>$1.00 USD</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="amount-paid">
  <td>Row 2</td>
  <td>$2.69 USD</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi I made a small change in code it is work for this code.can u post again the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using innerHTML instead of text like this:

$('#amount-paid td:eq(1)').innerHTML = 'Paid';